# Keyboard hack on an OSX Mac to change bad typing habits

Tags: macos, keyboard

I had an idea (not sure whether it's original) that will force me to use the *Shift* keys correctly.

Is it possible for me to make the left hand shift key disable all other LH keys, and the right hand shift key disable all other RH keys, so that in order to get a !@#$% or ASDF, etc, I am forced to use the RH shift key, while in order to get &*() or JKL:, etc, I am forced to use the LH shift key?

I have gotten in the habit of capitalizing EVERYTHING with the LH pinky, and it's starting to hurt. I need a profound and radical retraining!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a utility called Karabiner (KeyRemap4Macbook) which looks promising.

https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html